# The %d for printf() is outputting large integers.

Tags: c, printf

I have been learning C programming, and have seemed to stumble upon %d giving me large integer values like 11146096.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main() {
    const int age = 23;
    int brotherage; 
    brotherage = age*2;
    printf("I am %d years old, and my uncle is %d years old.");
}
```

Comment: pay attention to your `printf` - how many `%d` do you have - where are the corresponding variables??

Comment: Your compiler should be outputting diagnostic messages indicating your missing arguments to printf. If it is, pay attention to them. If not, turn up the warnings level. On GCC, always use at least `gcc -Wall -Werror`.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Would you happen to know how to turn up the warning levels on Dev-C++?

Comment: No, but it's using GCC. Look for CFLAGS or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `printf` statment is wrong. You need to specify the variables for the corresponding `%d's` in your `printf` function :

```
printf("I am %d years old, and my uncle is %d years old.", age, brotherage);
```

A large number is printed in your case because, the `printf` function will assume that you have supplied the arguments for the `%d's` and go looking for it on the stack. It will pick up whatever is there, and hence, can return garbage values.

Answer (score 1):

This call has undefined behavior

```
printf("I am %d years old, and my uncle is %d years old.");
```

because there are less arguments than the number of format specifiers.

I think you mean

```
printf("I am %d years old, and my uncle is %d years old.\n", age, brotherage);
```

Take into account that according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Answer (score 0):

You've wrongly used the printf clouse, you've add the output variable for the format chars. change

```
printf("I am %d years old, and my uncle is %d years old.");
```

to

```
printf("I am %d years old, and my uncle is %d years old.", age, brotherage);
```

Comment: FYI. This answer is now in the Low Quality review queue. I suggest you [edit] it, to add a little explanation.

Answer (score -1):

you have made a mistake in the formatted output statement.
YOUR INCORRECT statement:

```
printf("I am %d years old, and my uncle is %d years old.");
```

CORRECT Statement:

```
printf("I am %d years old, and my uncle is %d years old.",age,brotherage);
```

Hence, u have missed out to code the variables in your output statement.